# Increasing transmission power in wifi, what are the disadvantages?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

Other than governmental restrictions, is there any reason that we can't just **increase** the power of wifi devices (Routers, APs and adapters) continuously until we reach actual power limits of a source?

I was wondering, because I don't really understand the **arbitrary** power limits by governments -- because at wifi frequencies, there are no harmful radiation effects and there seems to be a linear relationship between power and performance/range. Could there be health concerns?

Thanks for your reply!

EDIT: Thanks for your comments so far - I would like to avoid the typical cost/quality of building e.g. cheap devices won't be able to handle a high power output. Let's assume they can. Also, there seems to be some discussion that performance and range are connected (increase performance, decrease range): can anybody elaborate?

Comment: The limits aren't arbitrary because you don't understand them, and health concerns aren't the primary motivating factors.  The reasons you can't increase the power to whatever you want are the reasons for the regulations.  These aren't arbitrary and capricious numbers somebody pulled out of their butt.  They are developed by committees of experts, required to be no more restrictive than necessary, and reviewed during periods of public comment.  All of the underlying reasons are available in the regulations, which you can get for the asking.

Comment: Consider two scenarios: (A) Your neighbor (illegally) cranks up the power on his WAP, and now that interferes with your WiFi reception.  Still like the idea of no regulation?  (B) Your WiFi units output too much power that their receivers overload whenever they are with a meter of each other.  Cheap WiFi devices means limited power handling.

Comment: The limits are imposed to prevent your wifi router causing interference to other radio transmissions in the 2.4Ghz band (mobile phones, wireless doorbells, etc...)